# Simple exercise on Galois theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, splitting-field

Find the splitting field of $x^6-2x^4-8x^2+16$ over $\mathbb {F}_3$ and list the intermediate fields between the base camp and the splitting field.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Over $\mathbb{F}_3$ we have
$$
x^6-2x^4-8x^2+16=(x^2 + 2x + 2)(x^2 + x + 2)(x^2 + 1).
$$

Answer (score 2):

$x^6-2x^4-8x^2+16 = x^6+x^4+x^2+1$ in $\mathbb {F}_3[x]$.

$x^6+x^4+x^2+1 = \dfrac{x^8-1}{x^2-1} = (x^2 + 1) (x^4 + 1)$

Therefore, the splitting field of $x^6-2x^4-8x^2+16$ is the same as the splitting field of $x^4 + 1=(x^2 + x + 2) (x^2 + 2 x + 2)$, which is $\mathbb {F}_9$.

Comment: Didn't you forget the roots of $x^2 + 1$?

Comment: @user159517, the roots of $x^4 + 1$ contain the roots of $x^2 + 1$.

Comment: Nice! The given sextic is a factor of $x^8-1$ which already splits in $\Bbb{F}_9$ (as a factor of $x^9-x$). So it suffices to show that it doesn't split in $\Bbb{F}_3$ :-)

Answer (score -1):

My factorization was incorrect, I have understood my error. Now to calculate the Galois group of the extension (which is actually a Galois extension, as $\mathbb {F}_9$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial, having first derivative different from zero, with coefficients in $\mathbb {F}_3$) I just note that the degree of the extension is $[\mathbb {F}_9:\mathbb {F}_3]=2$, so the group has 2 elements and it is isomorphic to $\mathbb {Z}_2$. Is it right?